# Trouble ADDING points to quiz game. It adds 2 instead of 1. JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked into the stackoverflow recommendations about posts with similar titles and nothing solved my issue. Im new to JS, im trying to make a simple multiple choice quiz. If you get it correct you score a point, if not, u don't get any but the question counter increases, the thing is **after the first question everything adds double the value**, here's a quick video showcasing de error: https://gyazo.com/9fbdf63508b2713992935d813f29788e  pay attention to the bottom-right corner.

This is a side project and I've been stuck on it for almost 2 weeks now.. no joke. Any help is extremely appreciated, my main language is Spanish so that's the reason of the variables names. Here's the code:

```js
let pregunta = document.getElementById('preguntafinal');
let puntaje = document.getElementById('puntaje');
let opcion1 = document.getElementById('opcion1');
let opcion2 = document.getElementById('opcion2');
let opcion3 = document.getElementById('opcion3');
let opcion4 = document.getElementById('opcion4');
let puntito1 = document.querySelector('puntito1');
let idPreg = 0;
let respSeleccionada;
let puntosTotales = 0;
let preguntasTotales = 0;

function iterarJuego() {
  pregunta.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].preg;
  opcion1.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcionuno;
  opcion2.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciondos;
  opcion3.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciontres;
  opcion4.innerText = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcioncuatro;;
  elegirRespuesta();
}

function elegirRespuesta() {
  opcion1.addEventListener("click", asd => {
    respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcionuno;
    funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);
  });
  opcion2.addEventListener("click", asd => {
    respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciondos;
    funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);
  });

  opcion3.addEventListener("click", asd => {
    respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opciontres;
    funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);
  });

  opcion4.addEventListener("click", asd => {
    respSeleccionada = arrayPreguntas[idPreg].opcioncuatro;
    funAnalizar(respSeleccionada);
  });
}

function funAnalizar() {
  console.log(respSeleccionada);
  console.log(arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error);
  if (respSeleccionada == arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error) {
    console.log("correcto");
    respCorrecta(respSeleccionada);
  } else if (respSeleccionada != arrayPreguntas[idPreg].error) {
    console.log("incorrecto");
    respIncorrecta(respSeleccionada);
  }
}

function respCorrecta() {
  puntosTotales++;
  preguntasTotales++;
  puntaje.innerText = puntosTotales + "/" + preguntasTotales;
  idPreg++;
  iterarJuego(idPreg);
  console.log("ja");
}

function respIncorrecta() {
  preguntasTotales++;
  puntaje.innerText = puntosTotales + "/" + preguntasTotales;
  idPreg++;
  iterarJuego(idPreg);
  console.log("jant");
}

arrayPreguntas = [{
  idPreg: 0,
  preg: "Que significa AI en Japonés?",
  opcionuno: 'amor',
  opciondos: 'carcel',
  opciontres: 'pizza',
  opcioncuatro: 'caja',
  error: 'amor'
}, {
  idPreg: 1,
  preg: "Cual es el hiragana 'ME' ?",
  opcionuno: 'ぬ',
  opciondos: 'ね',
  opciontres: 'ぐ',
  opcioncuatro: 'め',
  error: 'め'
}, {
  idPreg: 2,
  preg: "En hiragana: DESAYUNO , ALMUERZO , CENA ?",
  opcionuno: 'ぬ',
  opciondos: 'ね',
  opciontres: 'ぐ',
  opcioncuatro: 'め',
  error: 'め'
}, {
  idPreg: 3,
  preg: "Como se dice madre y padre ?",
  opcionuno: 'chichi hana',
  opciondos: 'hana mitsu',
  opciontres: 'kirei chichi',
  opcioncuatro: 'undo chichi',
  error: 'kirei chichi'
}, {
  idPreg: 4,
  preg: "Que significa きれい ?",
  opcionuno: 'rey y reina',
  opciondos: 'lindo y linda',
  opciontres: 'hermoso y hermosa',
  opcioncuatro: 'salvaje y saldro',
  error: 'lindo y linda'
}]

iterarJuego();
```

That's the .js ..if for some reason the html is needed ill add it with an edit.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Redid everything into English, it was messy (BTW there's a button called "Tidy" in the editor) but I couldn't find the bug, I might've corrected it without being aware I had? Anyways, I liked the flow of the code so instead of giving up I made some improvements.

The terse syntax is from [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) interface:

**Figure I**

```js
// <form id="QA"> name attribute can be used as id
const QA = document.forms.QA; 
// We can make a reference to all form controls in <form>
const IO = QA.elements;
// With that defined, referencing form controls is simple
IO.question // <output id='question'>
IO.next     // <button id='next'>
```

The [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interface allows us to group [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content) by a common name attribute and use array methods on them or extract a value of a checked or selected form control:

**Figure II**

```js
// 1 of 4 <input id='optB' name='opt' type='radio' value='optB' checked>
IO.opt       // HTMLCollection of all [name='opt']
[...IO.opt]  // Array of all [name='opt']
IO.opt.value // Automatically gets the value of the checked [name='opt']
```

I replaced the 4 click handlers with one submit handler:

**Figure III**

```js
// <form> is bound to the submit event
QA.onsubmit = evaluate;
function evaluate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

If you decide to handle the submit event remember to use `e.preventDefault()`
otherwise the  will attempt to send data to a server, and the response
will kill the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    html {
      font: 300 3ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'
    }
    
    #score {
      font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    
    #score::before {
      content: 'Score: '
    }
    
    ol {
      list-style: lower-latin;
      margin-top: 0
    }
    
    input,
    button {
      font: inherit
    }
    
    li {
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    
    button {
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 0.5rem;
      cursor: pointer
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <form id='QA'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><output id='score'></output></legend>
        <output id='question'></output>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <input id='optA' name='opt' type='radio' value='optA'>
            <label for='optA'></label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input id='optB' name='opt' type='radio' value='optB'>
            <label for='optB'></label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input id='optC' name='opt' type='radio' value='optC'>
            <label for='optC'></label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input id='optD' name='opt' type='radio' value='optD'>
            <label for='optD'></label>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <menu>
          <button id='next'>Next</button>
        </menu>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script>
    const QA = document.forms.QA;
    const IO = QA.elements;
    const question = IO.question;
    const score = IO.score;
    const opt1 = IO.optA.nextElementSibling;
    const opt2 = IO.optB.nextElementSibling;
    const opt3 = IO.optC.nextElementSibling;
    const opt4 = IO.optD.nextElementSibling;

    let qID = 0;
    let totalP = 0;
    let totalQ = 0;

    function quiz() {
      question.textContent = (qID + 1) + '. ' + qArray[qID].ques;
      opt1.textContent = qArray[qID].optA;
      opt2.textContent = qArray[qID].optB;
      opt3.textContent = qArray[qID].optC;
      opt4.textContent = qArray[qID].optD;

      [...IO.opt].forEach(o => {
        if (o.checked) {
          o.checked = false;
        }
      });
    }

    QA.onsubmit = evaluate;

    function evaluate(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let selected = IO.opt.value;

      if (selected === qArray[qID].right) {
        correct();
      } else {
        wrong();
      }
    }

    function correct() {
      totalP++;
      totalQ++;
      score.textContent = totalP + " / " + totalQ;
      qID++;
      if (qID >= qArray.length) {
        return IO.next.style.display = 'none';
      }
      quiz();
    }

    function wrong() {
      totalQ++;
      score.textContent = totalP + " / " + totalQ;
      qID++;
      if (qID >= qArray.length) {
        return IO.next.style.display = 'none';
      }
      quiz();
    }

    qArray = [{
      qID: 0,
      ques: "Que significa AI en Japonés?",
      optA: 'amor',
      optB: 'carcel',
      optC: 'pizza',
      optD: 'caja',
      right: 'optA'
    }, {
      qID: 1,
      ques: "Cual es el hiragana 'ME' ?",
      optA: 'ぬ',
      optB: 'ね',
      optC: 'ぐ',
      optD: 'め',
      right: 'optD'
    }, {
      qID: 2,
      ques: "En hiragana: DESAYUNO , ALMUERZO , CENA ?",
      optA: 'ぬ',
      optB: 'ね',
      optC: 'ぐ',
      optD: 'め',
      right: 'optB'
    }, {
      qID: 3,
      ques: "Como se dice madre y padre ?",
      optA: 'chichi hana',
      optB: 'hana mitsu',
      optC: 'kirei chichi',
      optD: 'undo chichi',
      right: 'optC'
    }, {
      qID: 4,
      ques: "Que significa きれい ?",
      optA: 'rey y reina',
      optB: 'lindo y linda',
      optC: 'hermoso y hermosa',
      optD: 'salvaje y saldro',
      right: 'optB'
    }];

    quiz();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```